# Why Veracode thinks that the name of variables are flaws, while we know that those names are going to change in production build?

Tags: reactjs, security, static-analysis, veracode

I have a react app, and I zip the dist folder and use it for Veracode static scan. I searched and reached that I should let *.map file to be there for veracode, but Veracode show me some flaws about name of some javascript objects in my code, for example I have a `const myPassword = '*********';` and we know that in production build of webpack these variable names will change, then why Veracode shows these cases as flaws?

I need to add that I send the final js build without .map file and I receive 100% ok from Veracode. is it a flaw in Veracode?

Comment: Most certainly not a flaw. It's warning you that you should not store secrets (passwords) in the source code, apart from very special cases maybe. But having a variable that's called mySecret with a hard-coded value is very much indicative of a security vulnerability.

Comment: No, for example in formik you have to set place holder of text inputs in form by sending a JSON object and in that object if you defined a place holder with text "please enter your password here" then vera code show a medium flaw for that line of code!

Comment: I still think this is a good finding in the sense that Veracode had no chance to know. But of course it's not a vulnerability then and you can mark it as false positive.